# Single Logout on WSO2 Identity Server 4.5

Tags: wso2, saml, wso2-identity-server

Since WSO2 official SSOAgent has too many dependencies, I've developed my sso filter to handle SAML request/response.
When I migrate to IS 4.5, SSO seems all right, but single logout doesn't work anymore. 
After posting logout request, I keep getting redirect page with all null parameters(form action=null, SAMLResponse=null, relayStates=null), and get redirected to console login page instead of my app, thus I can't do my logout.

My SAMLRequest seems like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<saml2p:LogoutRequest xmlns:saml2p="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" Destination="https://is-dev.com:9443/samlsso" ID="ebdokpbchiddgikaolkibeifeccocjcajdgbjokd" IssueInstant="2013-11-23T21:38:45.487Z" NotOnOrAfter="2013-11-23T21:43:45.487Z" Reason="Single Logout">
    <saml2:Issuer xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:entity">sample</saml2:Issuer>
    <saml2:NameID xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress">DOMAIN.COM/jack@domain.com</saml2:NameID>
    <saml2p:SessionIndex>3fdf4df7-4b0a-4c20-8fe2-01701c78161f</saml2p:SessionIndex>
</saml2p:LogoutRequest>
```

I don't see anything wront whith it. And i keep getting such ERROR from backend:

> ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.processors.LogoutRequestProcessor} -  28adcd7b-ad16-43b7-b57b-6defb3a33fda]. Expected: [56293095-95e4-4379-a723-3e1e6b4c939a] {org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.processors.LogoutRequestProcessor}

Anyone knows if it's relavant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems to be that the "SessionIndex" that is sent via in the SAML logout response is not valid. `Expected: [56293095-95e4-4379-a723-3e1e6b4c939a]`   IDP seems to be expecting some thing else. I guess what you can do is,  Please tract the  SAML response from IDP --> SP. (when login). In that request, you can find the "SessionIndex" and verify you are sending same "SessionIndex" in the logout request. For more details you can refer [this](http://www.soasecurity.org/2013/06/how-saml2-single-logot-works.html)